# pandas dataframe for matrix of values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, time, series

I have 3 things:

1. A time series 1D array of certain length.
2. A matrix of stellar flux values of equal column length as the time series (as each star in the field was observed according to the time array) but ~3000 rows deep as there are ~3000 observed stars in this field.
3. An array of ~3000 star ID's to go with the ~3000 time-series flux recordings mentioned above.

I'm trying to turn all of this into a pandas.DataFrame for extracting timeseries features using the module 'tsfresh'. Link [here](http://tsfresh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/text/quick_start.html).

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this? It should read somewhat like a table with a row of ID's as headers, a column of time values and ~3000 columns of flux values for the stars.

I've seen examples of it being done on the page I've linked i.e. multiple 'value' columns (in this case they would be flux values). But no indication of how to construct them.

This data frame will then be used for machine learning if that makes any difference.

Many thanks for any help that can be offered!

Comment: what's your data stored in now, csvs?

Comment: numpy arrays :) time and ID's are 1d numpy arrays and flux values are in a 2d numpy array

Comment: what have you tried so far? please provide code. it's not hard to convert numpy arrays to Pandas Series and DataFrames, you could find that quickly on google. so please try some code and restrict your question here to where you get stuck.

Comment: my method is to use 
pandas.DataFrame(column_id= IDs, column_sort= time, column_value = fluxes)
where IDs = the ID's array, time = time array, fluxes = flux 2D array
but it errors out saying column_value is not identified as an element the function can take and when left out doesn't include the flux values (which would obviously happen)
I'm afraid I can't supply more specific code as it concerns material not available to the public yet. Thanks

Comment: Call the function on `fluxes`, and instead of `column_id` use `columns`, and finally use `index` for the time array.

Comment: ah that's a great idea thank you! I'll post how it goes

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you Victor C. :)